# Concepts in C++20

Tags: c++, c++20

I recently started programming in c++. I'm trying to learn concepts represented in c++20. While I was doing my assignament I came a cross a problem. Can someone tell why this doesn't want to compile?

It reports:

```
1.Error C3864 'ns1::BufferedCollection<T>': requires clause is incompatible with the declaration for each function
```

BufferedCollectionHeader.h

```
namespace ns1
{
    template<typename T>
    concept AddableComparable= requires (const T& a,const T& b)
    {
        {a + b} -> std::convertible_to<T>;
        {a < b} -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
    };

    template<typename T>
    concept Printable = requires(std::ostream stream,const T& a)
    {
        {stream << a} -> std::convertible_to<decltype(stream)>;
    };

    template<typename T>
    concept AddableComparablePrintable = AddableComparable<T> && Printable<T>;

    template<typename T>
    requires AddableComparablePrintable<T>
    class BufferedCollection : public IPrintable
    {
        static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable<T>::value, "Tip T nije copy_assignable");
        static_assert(std::is_move_assignable<T>::value, "Tip T nije move_assignable");
        int elements;
        int buffers;
        int capacity;

        template<typename K>
        struct Node
        {
            int capacity;
            K* p;
            Node<K>* next;
        };

        Node<T>* list;
    public:
        BufferedCollection(int)noexcept;
        ...
    };
}
```

BufferedCollection.h

```
#include "BufferedCollectionHeader"
template<typename T>
requires ns1::AddableComparablePrintable<T>
ns1::BufferedCollection<T>::BufferedCollection(int n)noexcept: elements(0),buffers(0),capacity(n),list(nullptr){};
...
```

Source.cpp

```
class TestClass:public ns1::IPrintable
{
    int x;
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const TestClass& test)
    {
        stream << test.to_string();
        return stream;
    }
    TestClass(int n):x(n){}
    std::string to_string()const noexcept override
    {
        return std::to_string(x);
    }
    TestClass operator+(const TestClass& t)const
    {
        return TestClass(t.x + x);
    }
    bool operator<(const TestClass& t)const
    {
        return true;
    }
};
int main()
{
    ns1::BufferedCollection<TestClass>  bc(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- IPrintable is abstract class that represents printable objects.
- I distributed code for class BufferedCollection in two files because it's required in assignment

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The two files may be requires for your assignment, but this question should use just one block of code to demonstrate the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`concept Printable = requires(std::ostream stream,const T& a)` should  get a reference as input (and in the friend definition as well!):

```
    template<typename T>
    concept Printable = requires(std::ostream &stream,const T& a)
                                              ^~~~~~~                                              
    {
        {stream << a} -> std::convertible_to<decltype(stream)>;
    };
```

In addition to that, the addition and compare operator of your `TestClass` should be marked `const`. If you change this it compiles fine: [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YeocGs). I further simplified your example and put it into a single file. Therefore, I am not sure if this solves all of your problems.

**UPDATE**

As can be seen from this [comparison](https://godbolt.org/z/7e7WYY), GCC and clang compile but MSVC still rejects the code.

Comment: I forgot thet...It still doesn't work for me.
Error C2264 'ns1::BufferedCollection<TestClass>::BufferedCollection': error in function definition or declaration; function not called and still error number 1

Comment: @gprincip Have a look at this [comparison](https://godbolt.org/z/7e7WYY). Apparently, only MSVC (which I suppose you are using) rejects the code and give the two errors you got. GCC and clang accept it.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thank you. Also I solved it(I just put concepts outside of  the namespace ns1), so now MSVC accepts too.

Comment: @gprincip Based on your problem I was able to reduce the problem to its core and asked a related question. I got this nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65703003/8359552). This would allow your concepts to stay in the namespace ```nsp```.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't take streams by value. They are not copyable.

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const TestClass& test)
```

You need to const qualify your `+` and `<`, because the constraints look at `const T &`

```
TestClass operator+(const TestClass& t) const;
bool operator<(const TestClass& t) const;
```

Aside: why are you defining a concept for *only* `+`, `<<` and `<`? What's wrong with `std::three_way_comparable`?

Why `static_assert` assignability, and not concept that?

Comment: Still doesn't work, now it reports also  Error C2264 'ns1::BufferedCollection<TestClass>::BufferedCollection': error in function definition or declaration; function not called. I used static_assert because it's required in assignment.

Comment: works fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f04efb01acb016b1)