# C++20 Concepts: out-of-line-definition fails with MSVC but not in GCC or clang

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Consider this little code snippet

```
namespace nsp
{
    template<typename T>
    concept Addable= requires(const T& a,const T& b)
    {
        {a + b} -> std::convertible_to<T>;
    };

    template<Addable T>
    struct C
    {
        C();
    };
}

template<nsp::Addable T>
nsp::C<T>::C() {};
```

As shown [here](https://godbolt.org/z/jbcnxE) GCC (10.2) and clang (11.0) accept the code while MSVC (x86 19.28) rejects it with the error message:

```
error C3855: 'nsp::C<T>': template parameter 'T' is incompatible with the declaration.
```

Is this a MSVC bug or are GCC and clang wrong accepting it? Or alternatively, did I something stupid? If I move the out-of-line definition into the namespace `nsp` it seems to work for MSVC, as well. See this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/ojKGEW).

Comment: @Mgetz I updated my question and included the compiler versions.

Comment: Are you compiling with `/std:c++latest`? (I'm not sure if `/std:c++20` works yet).

Comment: I cannot seem to find this specific language feature under that name, but do you know of the existence of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support ?

Comment: Concepts are a novelty so probably just a msvc bug/not yet implemented feature. Until it's fixed define it at the point of declaration.

Comment: @JHBonarius I use ```/std:c++latest```

Comment: @YVbakker It's called "Concepts", and according to the linked page MSVC only has partial support.

Comment: [No compiler supports all C++20 features](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support). There are features that work in MSVC but not GCC. MSVC updates are less frequent than GCC. On the other hand, a common complaint with GCC is how often the compiler changes under your feet.

Comment: @YVbakker and Yksisarvinen: Thank you for the hints.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen ah great! I learned something new today as well then

Comment: Implementation priorities are different too. GCC is better in language features, MSVC in library features BUT - MSVC offers full support for modules. Modules are important if you want to introduce NPM-style package management

Comment: @Hack06 I was just curious which compiler was right to (not) accept the code. I don't work on a specific problem.

Comment: @Hack20 the c++20 standard has been finalized. We should be starting to learn and adapt it. I wouldn't consider it "a rush" at all.

Comment: @JHBonarius Then why here https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx20 I read "Important: Because the ISO C++20 standard is very recent, GCC's support is experimental." ? I mean if you're ok to experiment with your code with some chance of it being error-prone then go ahead! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is an observable deviation in MSVC that has been seen usually in the context of templates and SFINAE. MSVC tends to have difficulty with out-of-line definitions of templates that have qualifications when the declarations are not qualified (from being in the same namespace). I've often encountered this when dealing with forms of SFINAE, and it appears this must be also occurring with `concept`s now too.

For example, MSVC rejects the valid code:

```cpp
namespace nsp {

  template <typename T>
  using is_convertible_to_bool = std::is_convertible<T, bool>;

  template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_convertible_to_bool<T>::value,int> = 0>
  void example(const T& x);

} // namespace nsp

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<nsp::is_convertible_to_bool<T>::value,int>>
void nsp::example(const T& x)
{

}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/j9f3dq)</kbd>

However, MSVC will accept the same code, provided you add qualifications on the `is_convertible_to_bool` from `namespace nsp`:

```cpp
  template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<nsp::is_convertible_to_bool<T>::value,int> = 0>
  //                                     ^~~~~ fixes it
  void example(const T& x);
```

<kbd>[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/1YEbvn)</kbd>

Similarly, your code sample actually works if you change the definition of `struct C` to include the fully qualified concept name:

```cpp
    template<nsp::Addable T>
    //       ^~~~~
    //       Qualifying here fixes the failure in MSVC
    struct C
    {
        C();
    };
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/rErbdz)</kbd>

---

I don't have time to check the standard for lookup rules for which compiler is correct (will do this later if no other answer appears), but my expectation is actually that MSVC is providing **incorrect** behavior. The basic name lookup should select the same type in both definitions, and thus the code *should be* well-formed.